# validate length of each element of List

Tags: java, string, list, collections

Given a `List<String>` of size 10:

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList(new String[10]);
```

How can I ensure that each string in the list is less than 1000 characters long? I know I can iterate through the list, but I was wondering whether there was a cleverer approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for one-liner solution you can use streams added in Java 8 and its `allMatch(Predicate)` method

```
List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("123","12","1","12345");

System.out.println(messages.stream().allMatch(s -> s.length()<5));//false
System.out.println(messages.stream().allMatch(s -> s.length()<6));//true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrapper around `String` and validate `String` length in its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

@Pshemo Answer is awesome! (+1)

Here's another approach without using streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> messages = Arrays.asList("abc","ab","a","abcdef","abcdefg");
    System.out.println(validateList(messages, 7)); // True
    System.out.println(validateList(messages, 6)); // False
}

public static boolean validateList(List<String> messages, int qualifier) {
    for (String message : messages) {
        if (message.length() > qualifier) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Results:

```
true
false
```